# AJAX call triggers success callback even if server script exists with error

Tags: php, ajax, callback

Even though the below PHP code exits with an error, the `success` callback in the AJAX code is still being triggered. Why is that?

JavaScript code :

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: xxxx,
            data: {info:data},
            success: function(result){
               //code here
            },
            error:function(msg)
            {
                alert('add data error,please add again');
            }
        });
```

php code:

```
        if(is_wrong) //data is error
        {
            exit("the data is not right,please add again");
        }
```

Comment: What is your PHP code?

Comment: The success callback in jquery ajax will always be triggered if the ***ajax request*** is successful. It is irrespective of what response you get or do not get from your php file. If there is an error with the *request* only then will the error callback function be executed.

Answer (score 0):

There are various ways to handle error or success, when communicating between the client and server.

**1. with HTTP status code**

One of the `$.ajax()` callbacks (`success` and `error`) will be called, depending on the [HTTP status code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes) returned by the server. The "normal" success code is 200 OK. When you send output with a PHP script, if everything goes well, your generated content will be sent with code 200.

This is the case when you call `exit()` here. From the point of view of your client-side JavaScript code, since it received status code 200 OK, it will call the `success` callback. If you want the error callback to execute, you have to send custom headers in your PHP code, *before* sending any other output.

You can achieve this with the [header function](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.header.php). For example, the following code can be used to generate a "404 Not Found" status:

```
header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
```

Here you would need to find another HTTP code that corresponds to your code better. I don't think this approach is the best solution, because HTTP status codes are meant to be server status codes, i.e. not meant for reflecting application error codes.

**2. with your own conventions**

The other way would be to handle the application error codes would be to handle everything from the `success()` handler. You don't set error codes from your PHP, but establish a convention to tell when you have an application error or a normal case. You would still keep  the `error()` callback, so that you can handle various HTTP errors (i.e. if your connection to the server is broken).

For example, if you send your data from the server to the client as JSON, you might send from your php:

```
if(is_right) //data is ok
{
    $response = array(
        'data' => $someData, // any data you might want to send back to the client
    );
}
if(is_wrong) //data is error
{
    $response = array(
        'error' => "the data is not right,please add again"
    );
}
// Called in both cases
exit(json_encode($response));
```

In your client-side code, you would have:

```
...,
success: function(result) {
    if(data.error !== undefined) {
        // do something if your server sent an error
        console.log(data.error);
    }
    else {
        var data = result.data;
        // do something with the data
    }
},
...
```

Comment: appreciate.that is exactly what i'm used in my application.